# How can I limit .htaccess to current directory scope only?

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting, httpd

I have something like this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "index\.php|api\.html|api_fetch\.js">
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /blog>
Allow from all
</Directory>
RewriteEngine off
```

The idea is to limit access in current directory (this one happen to be www-root) to whitelisted stuff and let `.htaccess` in any other directory, if there is one, do their own stuff. So this way, when I visit `www.example.com/blog/`, `.htaccess` generated by WordPress will do its work.

The problem is that `.htaccess` seems to be applying rules globally so my `/blog/` gets the same restrictions.

How can I scope specific `.htaccess` per dir and let others do their job recursively starting from RewriteBase (i.e. WP's `RewriteBase /blog/` should continue recursively everywhere unless specific directory like `wp-admin/` as its own `.htaccess`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite to control access, instead of mod_authz_...

**UPDATE:** Because in `.htaccess` you simply don't have the fine grained control you require to limit access to a specific directory using the mod_authz_... directives. You would need access to the server config / VirtualHost. An inherent feature of `.htaccess` (*directory* context) is that it applies to the current directory and all subdirectories.

mod_rewrite is a powerful module that gives you the fine grained control you require. Since mod_rewrite is not inherited (by default), any mod_rewrite directives in subdirectories will naturally override directives in the parent - which would seem to be what you require.

Alternatively, you rethink your current directory structure and move the files that you want to protect into their own subdirectory - this is then trivial to "protect". Having a mixture of files you want to deny and allow access to in the current directory, whilst allowing all subdirectories is a bit of a code smell and inherently adds an additional layer of complexity.

Any mod_rewrite directives in subdirectories (eg. `/blog/.htaccess`) will naturally override this. In order to access other subdirectories you just need to make sure you only target the current directory.

For example:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

# Block all requests that target files in the current directory
# except for "index.php", "api.html" and "api_fetch.js"
# All virtual URLs are still allowed and passed through to the front-controller below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|api\.html|api_fetch\.js)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ - [F]

# Front-controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

---

*Aside:* I realise this is pseudo-ish code, but...

> ```
> :
> <Directory /blog>
> Allow from all
> </Directory>
> RewriteEngine off
> ```

- The `Allow`, `Deny` and `Order` directives are deprecated on Apache 2.4 and should be replaced with the new `Require` (mod_authz_...) directives. These older directives have been moved to mod_access_compat and are provided for backwards compatibility only.
- The `<Director>` container is not permitted in `.htaccess`, this can only be used in a server or virtualhost context.
- The `RewriteEngine off` directive at the end of the file disables the rewrite engine for the *entire* file. (The *last* instance of this directives "wins".)

Comment: `Use mod_rewrite to control access, instead of mod_auth...` Why? Also, there seems to be some error with your logic since it forbids all file access.

Comment: Sorry, was missing a slash on the _CondPattern_. Basically, mod_rewrite gives you the fine grained control you require, the mod_authz_.... directives don't - when used in a _directory_ context. You need access to the server config to do more. I've updated my answer.

Comment: There may be a better solution if we know more specifics about your system. For instance, what files are you wanting to protect and why?

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense, so `%{REQUEST_URI}` is full request, including `/`? like `t.co/my_request` will be `/my_request` for $URI? As for what I'm trying to achieve - just general knowledge of basic security. Right  now I have a few files user should be able to access in root + I want to make `/blog/` where Wordpress is stricter but since WP is somewhat dynamic (especially wp-content and uploads) there are no 100% rules so I need to get general understanding of how such kind of protection usually is done so I can apply to other cases a swell.

Comment: Yes, the `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path, including the slash prefix. Unlike the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against, which does not include the slash prefix (because the directory-preifx, that ends in a slash, is first removed.) A slight complication in the code you've posted is that you have a front-controller that routes all _virtual_ URLs to `index.php` - so whilst you are blocking some _files_, you need to allow all URLs that don't map to files.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, it is a bit complex but I found no other way. Honestly, the whole Rewrite thing is jank as f*k and feels lke an outdated mammoth. I appreciate the help. Anything you can point me towards to read about WP? I just want to use it as a base example to get more in-depth understanding.

Comment: To block access to specific files in `.htaccess` you would generally use `<Files>` or `<FilesMatch>` containers, but note that this does apply to subdirectories as well. In fact, many WP installs will block access to specific files using this method. If you have access to the server config you do have much more control... for instance, you can use the `<DirectoryMatch>` container to target a specific directory (requires Apache 2.4+).

Comment: "the whole Rewrite thing is jank as f*k" - Well, mod_rewrite is a powerful beast and that naturally comes with additional complexity. However, using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` is more complex than when used directly in the server config (or virtual host). Other web servers don't have an equivalent of `.htaccess` (a per-directory config file), so they largely avoid the complexity by simply not supporting this feature. Having dabbled with Nginx and IIS web.config there are a lot of similarities - each have their quirks and frustrations.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate all the info. Last question: is there a difference for me to block access to directory `/pivate/` in `www-root` via `.htaccess` in `www-root` or in the `/pivate/` itself? Which one would you recommend? From quick-glance, having majority of the rules centralized in root `.htaccess` makes some things easier to manage.

Comment: "having majority of the rules centralized in root .htaccess makes some things easier to manage" - Yes, having a single `.htaccess` file in the root is generally preferred. However, in this case it may be simpler / more reliable to have a single `Require all denied` directive in the `/private/.htaccess` file.

Comment: `However, in this case it may be simpler / more reliable to have a single Require all denied directive in the /private/.htaccess file` - huh, why would it be?

Comment: Well, it depends on your environment and what you are doing... If you are blocking the directory in the root `.htaccess` then you are limited to using mod_rewrite or perhaps an Apache expression (on later versions) - this is inherently (slightly) more complex, more prone to error and crucially more prone to conflicts with other directives. This can also be potentially overridden by directives elsewhere. mod_rewrite is also an extension, it's not a core module. Whereas using mod_authz_core in a subdirectory cannot be overridden, no conflicts and is compiled into Apache by default.